# How can I compute the average of a nested SQL statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this crazy nested sql statement and it returns something like this:

[image: Results]

However, what I want is to use this data in the image to return 2 columns. **col_1**:`SUM(avgWithCriteria)/43` and **col_2**:`SUM(avgWithoutCriteria)/43`. How can I do this by adding onto my query below?

```
    SELECT
    ( ( avgWithCriteria - totalAverage ) / ( ( avgWithCriteria + totalAverage ) / 2 ) ) * 100 as percentDifference,
    a.*
FROM 
    (SELECT
        AVG( CASE WHEN 'f' not in ( has_free_parking ) THEN price ELSE null END) as avgWithCriteria,
        AVG( CASE WHEN 'f'        in ( has_free_parking ) THEN price ELSE null END) as avgWithoutCriteria,
        AVG( price ) as totalAverage,
        neighbourhood_cleansed
    FROM listings 
   WHERE city_name="berlin"
   AND price <= 1000000
   AND price >= -1
   AND reviews_per_month <= 1000000
   AND reviews_per_month >= -1
   AND est_monthly_income <= 1000000
   AND est_monthly_income >= -1
   GROUP BY neighbourhood_cleansed ) a;
```

Comment: ...,
SUM(avgWithCriteria)/43 AS col_1,
SUM(avgWithoutCriteria)/43 AS col_2,
a.* .......

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan can you append it into the original query please as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
SELECT percentDifference,avgWithCriteria,avgWithoutCriteria,totalAverage,neighbourhood_cleansed,
(col1_1/43) as col1,(col2_2/43) as col2
from
(
SELECT a.*,SUM(avgWithCriteria) as col1_1,SUM(avgWithoutCriteria) as col2_2
FROM
  (
SELECT
    ( ( avgWithCriteria - totalAverage ) / ( ( avgWithCriteria + totalAverage ) / 2 ) ) * 100 as percentDifference,
    a.*
FROM 
    (SELECT
        AVG( CASE WHEN 'f' not in ( has_free_parking ) THEN price ELSE null END) as avgWithCriteria,
        AVG( CASE WHEN 'f'        in ( has_free_parking ) THEN price ELSE null END) as avgWithoutCriteria,
        AVG( price ) as totalAverage,
        neighbourhood_cleansed
    FROM listings 
   WHERE city_name="berlin"
   AND price <= 1000000
   AND price >= -1
   AND reviews_per_month <= 1000000
   AND reviews_per_month >= -1
   AND est_monthly_income <= 1000000
   AND est_monthly_income >= -1
   GROUP BY neighbourhood_cleansed ) a
  ) a
GROUP BY percentDifference,avgWithCriteria,avgWithoutCriteria,totalAverage,neighbourhood_cleansed
) a;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! this is what I needed

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    ( ( avgWithCriteria - totalAverage ) / ( ( avgWithCriteria + totalAverage ) / 2 ) ) * 100 as percentDifference,
    SUM(avgWithCriteria)/43 AS col_1,
    SUM(avgWithoutCriteria)/43 AS col_2,
    a.*
FROM 
    (SELECT
        AVG( CASE WHEN 'f' not in ( has_free_parking ) THEN price ELSE null END) as avgWithCriteria,
        AVG( CASE WHEN 'f'        in ( has_free_parking ) THEN price ELSE null END) as avgWithoutCriteria,
        AVG( price ) as totalAverage,
        neighbourhood_cleansed
    FROM listings 
WHERE city_name="berlin"
AND price <= 1000000
AND price >= -1
AND reviews_per_month <= 1000000
AND reviews_per_month >= -1
AND est_monthly_income <= 1000000
AND est_monthly_income >= -1
GROUP BY neighbourhood_cleansed ) a;
```